# Having Issues booting After Update

Tags: boot

I tried to update to 20.04.2.0, I think not 100% sure, bootup became

`/dev/sda2: unexpected inconsistency run fsck manually`

I ran fsck -yf /dev/sda1, because I am a plug and play idiot.
Now i am getting a no boot error as follows

`/sbin/init: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-245.so: cannot open shared object file: no such file kernel panic - not sybcing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00`

Then there are a lot of other lines ending with kernel panic again. no access to a terminal window without running a boot usb. I don't remember my user name either sadly

Comment: Are you talking about an installed system? as there is no difference between then.  The 20.04.2.0 was a *respin* of some architecture ISOs (not all) due to an issue that impacted some; then a re-name of some to *increase* consistency.  It refers to ISOs only, and not installed systems (which are 20.04.2 for both)

Comment: Not sure, I updated from the pervious version and now there is a no boot error. All I got

Answer (score 0):

You have run `fsck` on `sda1`, but the error was for `sda2`?

As you can see from the error, the file  `libsystemd-shared-245.so` cannot be found, which `fsck` probably moved into `/lost+found` directory.

Your best bet here would be to just reinstall Ubuntu, but if that's not an option, I would boot from a ubuntu iso, then reinstall the `systemd`, which contains `libsystemd-shared-245.so`

- `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`
- `chroot /mnt /bin/bash`
- `apt-get reinstall systemd`

This could be a result of failing hardware; check for drive errors:
`smartctl --all /dev/sda`

Comment: So to answer your first question, yes. Then I did try the commands you gave and unfortunately they did not succeed in correcting the issue so I will just reinstall and replace the current OS. Oh well